# Connect electronJS with remote DB

Tags: javascript, electron

I've been using Javascript and Electron for a while and I need a little help. I have the following code that reads and writes correctly to a mysql database, on localhost. The problem is that I want to connect to a remote database, to read the local database and synchronize it with the remote one.

When I configure the connection parameters with those of the server, it does not work. How should I connect to the remote database? As a note, I have looked at the remote configuration and apparently everything is configured correctly.

Thank you.

Connecting code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',
    password:'',
    database:'electrondb'
});

module.exports = db
```

Code with which I try to connect remotely

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const dbremota = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'https://example.es',
    user:'root_example',
    password:'example_password',
    database:'test',
    localAddress: 'false'
});

module.exports = dbremota
```

Here the code that inserts into the DB

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron')
const path = require('path'); 

let db = require('./database');
const axios = require('axios');
let win;
function createWindow () {
   win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
     // nodeIntegration: true,
     // contextIsolation:true,
     // devTools:false,
     preload:path.join(app.getAppPath(), './index.js')
      
    }
  })

  win.loadFile('index.html')
}
ipcMain.handle('add', (event, obj) => {
  addProduct(obj)
});
function addProduct(obj)
{
  const sql = "INSERT INTO product SET ?";  
  db.query(sql, obj, (error, results, fields) => {
    if(error) {
       console.log(error);
    }
    getProducts()  
 });
}
```

Comment: Just saying "it does not work" is not helpful, what does not work?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, because thanks to the fact that I have sent the error code I have fallen into the error. I was calling a URL (Http://...) and had to call the server's IP. It has been call it and it works.

Thank you!

Comment: Ah ah, I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simply that on the remote connection I was calling a URL and had to call the server's IP.

Thank you!

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const dbremota = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'https://example.es',
    user:'root_example',
    password:'example_password',
    database:'test',
    localAddress: 'false'
});

module.exports = dbremota
```

Later:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const dbremota = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'111.222.333.444',
    user:'root_example',
    password:'example_password',
    database:'test',
    localAddress: 'false'
});

module.exports = dbremota
```